# I have a multi select vue element broken down by groups and want to limit the users selection by group

Tags: vue.js, user-interface, select, dashboard

I am new to vue so I'm not sure if this is a simple or hard question; but I have two groups one is for clients and one is for departments, I would like the user to be able to select one client and one department only.Any help would be great

```
 <el-select v-model="value" multiple filterable placeholder="Filters" >
  <el-option-group
      v-for="group in options"
      :key="group.label"
      :label="group.label">
    <el-option
        v-for="item in group.options"
        :key="item.value"
        :label="item.label"
        :value="item.value">
    </el-option>
  </el-option-group>
</el-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways to do this but one way is this:

For each group that you have, create a computed property that keeps track of whether or not one has been chosen in a group. Then add that `boolean` to `<el-option-group>` as `<el-option-group :disabled="groupOneChosen"/>`

The check can probably be something like:

`return this.value.some(element => this.group.options.includes(element))`.

You probably don't have to create computed properties for each if you want to keep track of them in an object, like:

```
computed: {
    groupsIncuded() {
        return {
            groupOne: this.value.some(element => this.group.options.includes(element))
        }
    }
}
```

And then check it in each group as `:disabled="groupsIncluded.groupOne"`